# Need help in ngx-graph links layout

Tags: d3.js, angular8, ngx-graph

I am trying to use ngx-graph in my project to draw a hierarchical graph. I have issue with links that connecting two nodes. I have tried all curve types, but not getting expected result.

**Here is some code snippets:**

**HTML**

```
[links]="links"
[nodes]="nodes"
[layoutSettings]="layoutSettings"
[curve]="curve"
[draggingEnabled]="false"
[panningEnabled]="true"
[enableZoom]="false"
[autoZoom]="true"
[autoCenter]="false"

<ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
<svg:g class="node">
<svg:rect [attr.width]="100" [attr.height]="50" fill ="#fff" stroke-width ="1" stroke = "#000" />
<svg:text alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="10" [attr.y]="node.dimension.height / 2">{{node.label}}</svg:text>
</svg:g>
</ng-template>
</ngx-graph>
```

**TS**

```
layoutSettings = {
orientation: 'TB'
};

nodes: Node[] = [
{
id: 'first',
label: 'Parent'
}, {
id: 'c1',
label: 'Child 1'
}, {
id: 'c2',
label: 'Child 2'
}, {
id: 'c3',
label: 'Child 3'
}
];

links: Edge[] = [
{
id: 'a',
source: 'first',
target: 'c1',
label: 'is parent of'
}, {
id: 'b',
source: 'first',
target: 'c2',
label: 'custom label'
}, {
id: 'c',
source: 'first',
target: 'c3',
label: 'custom label'
}
];
```

Output that I am getting is:

[image]

Expected output is:

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for my own question. This can be achieved by custom layouts.
[Here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/blob/184ce5aea8accadd6b72756a8d470e9da1d2d652/src/docs/demos/components/ngx-graph-org-tree/customDagreNodesOnly.ts) you can found a custom layout, which resolves my issue.

Comment: It's important to note that the 'shape.curveLinear' [interpolation function](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/demos/interactive-demo#line-curve-interpolation) is required to achieve the desired behavior.